# usage of sprintf conversion specifiers

Tags: c, string

The code is shown below:

```
static unsigned char text  [] [10] = {
    "/name",
    "/place", 
    "/address",
    "/office"
};

unsigned char l_my_file[80]; 

main()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0;i<5;i++)
    {  
        (void)sprintf((char *)l_my_file, "%s",text[i]);
    }
}
```

Now this sprintf is working really fine with all the strings printed properly.

Now the problem comes when I run my Quality Analysis check tool which pops up a message telling that `Argument type does not match conversion specifier number 1`.

Any suggestions on the conversion specifier used in `sprintf`?

Comment: What is the Quality Analysis check tool you're using?

Comment: @Michale...QAC is the name of the tool

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that your QA tool is insisting on `char *` (not `unsigned char *`) for the argument to `%s`.

Try declaring your array as `char` or casting `text[i]` to `char *`.

Comment: @Nemo...just changed from unsigned char to char and the QA tool isnt that warning at all.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be griping because the upper bounds of the text array in the loop will be 4 (index 0 through 4), but the way you have the array initialized it's upper bound is only 3 (index 0 through 3)?

Comment: This is certainly a bug in the code...  Upper bound should be `sizeof(text)/sizeof(text[0])`.  But that does not sound like what the tool is complaining about, at least to me.

Comment: That's a good catch (and the analysis tool should have caught it), but that would be a very weird diagnostic message for that problem.

Comment: I agree and after second thought it's more likely to be what Nemo pointed out.

Answer (score -1):

You're converting from a `const char[]` to an `unsigned char[]` for the contents of `text`.

What would happen if you tried to do `text[3][2] = 'x';`?

String literals are allowed to be in read-only memory. The array should be `const char[][]`, not `unsigned char[][]`.

Comment: No...  This declares an array of mutable strings and initializes them.  `text[3][2] = 'x';` will work fine.  That is not the problem.